# Is `concurrent.futures.map` thread-safe?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I find it not mentioned by the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map

Answer (score 5):

**Reference:**

According to [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor)

> Deadlocks can occur when the callable associated with a Future waits
>   on the results of another Future.

The 2 examples there shows how deadlock can happen. Try replacing `.submit()` with `.map()` and make the other necessary changes.`

**Under-the-hood:**

According to Python's `python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py` module (search your system for this file, the class `ThreadPoolExecutor` actually uses `queue.Queue()` (see line 107) to implement python threading and use the primitive `threading.Lock()` (see line 110) to lock the threads.

**Explanation:**

If to you "thread-safe" means multiple threads in a program each attempting to access a common data structure or location in memory, then you should know that `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` **allow only one thread to access the common data structure or location in memory at a time**; the `threading.Lock()` primitive is used to manage this. And when a function in one of your thread needs to wait for the results in another thread, then deadlock can occur and your code won't work; this you should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import time

resultDict = {0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: []}
resultDict1 = {0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: []}

def appendResult(a, b):
  result = a ** b
  resultDict[result % 5].append(result)
  time.sleep(1)

def appendResult1(a, b):
  result = a ** b
  resultDict1[result % 5].append(result)
  time.sleep(1)

startTime = time.time()
processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=12) as executor:
  for i in range(100):
    processes.append(executor.submit(appendResult, i, 2))

for task in as_completed(processes):
  task.result()

print("Cost", time.time() - startTime, "s")


startTime = time.time()
for i in range(100):
  appendResult1(i, 2)
print("Cost", time.time() - startTime, "s")
```

Yes, it's thread-safe. So resultDict and resultDict1 will be the same at the end of the above code.